# How to perform end to end test for react native apps that needs to perform actions on Gallery, Contacts, Other Apps (FB/Google auth) etc

Tags: ios, testing, react-native, automated-tests, end-to-end

In our application, we are currently using [Detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) to perform the end to end tests. We can perform actions like clicks, fill forms etc. using Detox. But since our app requires a Facebook and Google login, access gallery and contacts, we need to test those features too.

Is there any E2E framework that allows to perform actions on other apps / external services? Also if we need to mock these environments, is there any recommended approach?

Would really appreciate advices and suggestions on this topic.

Comment: curious if you found any answers. good question